# NodeJs websocket getting disconnected

Tags: node.js, websocket

My NodeJs server is using [websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) and accepting 2 connections, one from a web client (Firefox v83.0) and the other from an Android application.

Everything works fine and messages flow back and forth from the web client to the mobile and the opposite.

However, after what it looks to me some time of non-activity (like 30 or 60 secs) the websocket connection gets disconnected.

I have logged the close event in the server side like this:

```
wsServer.on('close', (data) => {
    console.log("CONNECTION CLOSED")
    console.log(data.closeReasonCode)
    console.log(data.closeDescription)
})
```

And what I get is:

```
1006
Peer not responding.
```

I googled the 1006 error and the docs only tells `connection was closed abnormally`...great explanation....thanks :S

I need some help figuring out what is going on here, and what is this `peer not responding` message that I get. Since I do not know if the issue is in the server, in any of the 2 clients, is it any timer that closes the connection that I am not aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to "symptoms" I would say you use nginx for reverse proxy.

Try to set

```
   proxy_read_timeout  600s; # deafult is 60 seconds
```

check [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout)

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, but to be honest, i did not know what was this nginx until i googled it from your comment, i do not think i am using it, unless it comes by default with Nodejs or something like that...

Comment: @codeKiller Do you have this problem only in production or in localhost too?

Comment: localhost only, i did not use it in production

Answer (score 0):

old question, but for others who will end up here with similar problem:

Most websocket implementations (Java certainly I bet others too) have an internal idle timeout, that can be adjusted when making a connection.

The above should solve the problem on localhost, but when connecting across the internet, you also need to send regular pings (usually every 55seconds is enough) to make sure that intermediary proxies and NAT routers don't kill your connection as idle. Unfortunately currently most browsers lack such capability, so this needs to be done on your server side.